# Can't find git-svn on Mac OS X Leopard after installing via MacPorts

Tags: svn, git, macos, git-svn, osx-leopard

Okay people, I'm sure someone has had this issue and can help me out.

I'm trying to get git-svn working on OSX Leopard (10.5.6). Using MacPorts I've run the install thus : sudo port install git-core +svn

However, git-svn has not been installed and is not available. No errors came up during the lengthy dependency installation and so I'm at a loss.

Thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could include some more detail about what you tried to do, what you expected, and what actually happened. The two answers so far have had to guess at what you did.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On my install at least, I have to invoke it as `git svn <cmd>` instead of `git-svn <cmd>`.

Comment: Thanks Hank, your suggestion worked perfectly. It never occurred to me to try something so simple :-)

Answer (score 2):

That's the same install I used which works fine. Have you added `/opt/local/bin` to your `PATH`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Greg. I did check the PATH and MacPorts had done it's job properly and added the /opt/local/bin correctly. Hank's suggestion about using git svn <cmd> seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

git-svn is located in /opt/local/libexex/git-core/ if installed through macports.
Add /opt/local/libexex/git-core to your path and you should be good to go.